# How to remove white-space at the front of a string using string split in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I was solving a problem on `string.split()`, but I couldn't find the solution to remove white-space at the start. Actually the problem is in the regular expression. It needs to be changed. I tried to solve by changing the expression several times but didn't work out. What will be the regular expression? Here is the code given below:

```
        String s = "           YES      leading spaces        are valid,    problemsetters are         evillllll";
        String delims = "[\\s._,?!'@\\t]+";                     
        String[] words = s.split(delims);
        System.out.println(words.length - 1);
        for(String w:words) {
            System.out.println(w);
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
```

output:

```
8

YES
leading
spaces
are
valid
problemsetters
are
evillllll
[, YES, leading, spaces, are, valid, problemsetters, are, evillllll]
```

Comment: Use trim() to remove white space from the start and then split the string

Answer (score 1):

You can use String class `trim()` method to remove the space *before* using `split`

Comment: Yes, this is the laconic answer that looked useful to me